# Python: Interact Dropdown - how to reference the output

Tags: python, dropdown, ipywidgets

Hi I have below dropdown:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual 
import ipywidgets as widgets

def f(Books):
    return Books
interact(f, Books=['a','b','c','d']);
```

This populates a dropdown list allowing user to choose from a, b, c, d.

Let's say user chooses one of the four.

How do you reference the result?

I want to use the output of the dropdown as a variable in other formulas.

ex.

```
if Books = a:
x = 1+1
```

Comment: what GUI library are you using? (where does `interact` come from?)

Comment: from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of recommending something that's generally terrible practice, I'd use a Global variable here. It's quick and easy, and given the interactive / prototyping nature of iPython, a lot of the usual arguments against global variables aren't super important.

Basically, every time you change a variable on the input of the interact widget, `f()` is called. So you simply must update this variable inside the function:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual 
import ipywidgets as widgets

myvar = ''

def f(Books):
    global myvar
    myvar = Books
    return Books

interact(f, Books=['a','b','c','d']);
```